# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' Inserting Item with Collection View Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, realm, xcode8

So, I am using Realm as a data store, which I'm pretty sure I need to first add content to before inserting an item at index path in a collection view. But I keep getting this all too familiar error:

`'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert item 1 into section -1, but there are only 1 items in section 1 after the update'`

Here is my model:

```
final class Listing: Object {
dynamic var id = ""
dynamic var name = ""
dynamic var item = ""

}
```

Here is my view controller that conforms to UICollectionView data sources and delegates:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // MARK: - Get Listings!

    queryListings()

    // MARK: - Delegates

    self.collectionView.delegate = self
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self
}

// MARK: - Query Listings

func queryListings() {
    let realm = try! Realm()

    let everyListing = realm.objects(Listing.self)
    let listingDates = everyArticle.sorted(byKeyPath: "created", ascending: false)

    for listing in listingDates {
        listing.append(listing)
        self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ 
            self.collectionView.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(item: self.listing.count, section: 1)])
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Delegates:

```
 // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

 func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return listing.count
}

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ListingCollectionViewCell

    cell.awakeFromNib()

    return cell
}
```

I've tried every permutation of self.listing.count 0, 1, -1 , +1 as well as section 0, 1, -1, +1 and the exception raised is the same plus or minus the section and items that exist. Calling reloadData() doesn't help either.

Anyone solve this with a collection view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines of code `for listing in listingDates { listing.append(listing) }` seem a bit unsafe. Either you're referring to separate objects named `listing` (such as a class property), or that's in reference to the same `listing` object. If listing is a Realm `Results` object, it shouldn't be possible to call `append` on it.

In any case, you're probably doing a bit more work than you need to. Realm objects, whether they are `Object` or `Results` are live, in that they'll automatically update if the underlying data changes them. As such, it's not necessary to perform multiple queries to update a collection view.

Best practice is to perform the query once, and save the `Results` object as a property of your view controller. From that point, you can use [Realm's Change Notification](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#collection-notifications) feature to assign a Swift closure that'll be executed each time the Realm query changes. This can then be used to animate the updates on the collection view:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
  var notificationToken: NotificationToken? = nil

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let results = realm.objects(Person.self).filter("age > 5")

    // Observe Results Notifications
    notificationToken = results.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
      guard let tableView = self?.tableView else { return }
      switch changes {
      case .initial:
        // Results are now populated and can be accessed without blocking the UI
        tableView.reloadData()
        break
      case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
        // Query results have changed, so apply them to the UITableView
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRows(at: insertions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                           with: .automatic)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}),
                           with: .automatic)
        tableView.reloadRows(at: modifications.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                           with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
        break
      case .error(let error):
        // An error occurred while opening the Realm file on the background worker thread
        fatalError("\(error)")
        break
      }
    }
  }

  deinit {
    notificationToken?.stop()
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey man - thanks a lot for your help! I can append a Listing but only after I log out and back in again, and call reloadData(). However I have been looking for your solution. The UiCollectionView version is simply insert, delete or reload items instead of rows, and setting the guard statement this way ` guard (self?.collectionView) != nil else { return }`.

Comment: I also have the results variable as thus: ` let results = realm.objects(Listing.self)` in the viewDidLoad with the rest of the code above modified for a collectionview. However, my variable at the top of my class is `let listing = [Listing]()`. When I run the code, now, all my data is gone including my collection view. It is simply a black screen (my background color is set to black).

Comment: Sorry -- forgot to mention `for listing in listingDates { listing.append(listing) }` is actually `listings.append(listing)`. So the top variable is `let listings = [Listing]()`. I am so sorry about the confusion. Been going hard the past few days.

Comment: So, looks like I still need to call this for loop to append my content ` for result in results { listings.append(result) }`. My realm variable is `let results = realm.objects(Article.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "created", ascending: false)`. So I can retrieve my data at launch but when I add a listing from another vc and unwind segue I crash with the same error: `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert item 1 into section -1, but there are only 1 items in section 1 after the update'`. I'm truly stuck.

Comment: Oh! Okay, no worries. Hmm, why are you copying the results of a Realm query to a Swift array then? You should be able to save the `Results` object as a property of your view controller and use that for the collection view. If you need to pass the data to another view controller, it'd still be less effort to just re-query in that one.

Comment: So, you're saying don't use an array? That is how I return number of items in section e.g. listings.count. How else can I query the Listing Object properties? For instance, my current delete code works perfectly in a simple `fun confirmDelete(indexPath: IndexPath)` : ` let listing = self.listings[indexPath.row] self.listings.remove(at: indexPath.item) try! self.realm.write() { self.realm.delete(listing) }`.

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example of this: **save the Results object as a property of your view controller and use that for the collection view**?

Comment: Okay, I realize the idiocy and redundancy of my previous question. I guess I'm asking, how do I return the index path count without an array? Or for that matter my cell for item at index path?

Comment: I tried something like this `realm.objects(Listing.self).count` and got this error  `fatal error: Index out of range
2017-03-01 16:22:07.156602 Article[7347:2541747] fatal error: Index out of range` which makes sense. Still trying.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**

With Realm, the mindset is different than what I'm accustomed to-- you're manipulating data that effects the table or collection, not the table or collection directly. Sounds obvious, but... anyway, TiM's answer is correct. Here's the collection view version:

```
// MARK: - Observe Results Notifications

    notificationToken = articles.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in

        guard (self?.collectionView) != nil else { return }

        // MARK: - Switch on State

        switch changes {

        case .initial:
            self?.collectionView.reloadData()
            break
        case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
            self?.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                self?.collectionView.insertItems(at: insertions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}))
                self?.collectionView.deleteItems(at: deletions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}))
                self?.collectionView.reloadItems(at: modifications.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}))
            }, completion: nil)
            break
        case .error(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            break
        }
    }
```